# 404 Not Found error when calling a Web API via jQuery

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have been dealing with a 404 Not Found error when calling a Web API in an ASP.NET MVC project for some time and I just do not find the problem. This is what I have.

***The WebApiConfig Class:***

```
public class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        //     name: "DefaultApi",
        //     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //     defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        // );

        EnableCorsAttribute cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);
    }
}
```

***The API Controller:***

```
public class Interactivas : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/VotoInteractiva/{parameters}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult RegistraVoto(String parameters)
    {
        // Server side services are called here.
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

***The Javascript code that consumes the Web API:***
This Javascript function is called when the user clicks a control in the View and is located directly in such a View not in a separate .js file. I included an "alert" to show the content of the "strURL" variable and it looks fine with the "parameter" at the end. When the AJAX call is made, the "error" part is triggered 
showing the 3 alerts: error, 404, Not Found. Also, I made sure my project runs in port 60642.

```
function RegistraVoto(id, puntos) {
    var strParametro = String(puntos) + String(id);
    var strURL = encodeURI("http://localhost:60642/api/VotoInteractiva/" + strParametro);

    $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: strURL,
            success: function (result) {
                alert('Resultado: ' + result)
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert('Error');
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
}
```

I have been watching, changing and testing all day long and I just cannot see what is wrong. I have also reviewed several similar support posts without success. I will very much appreciate any feedback.

P.D.: I am using .NET Framework 4.6.1

Respectfully,
Jorge Maldonado

Comment: Try generating the URL using the UrlHelper in the View (Assuming Razor) and see if it generates the same URL you hard-coded into the JavaScript.

Comment: Since this is a post-request you need to use the data-parameter of $.ajax. Data-parameter is described here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/